# I have query which insert rows in table, this table have add trigger, when I run this query this trigger raise error as follows:

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

**Error**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>
> Error Number:       512
>   Error Severity:      16
>   Error State:          1
>
> Error Procedure: AddBookingSlots

Code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AddDoctorBookingSlots]
ON [dbo].[BookingDay]
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @starttime AS DATETIME = (SELECT MyDateTime1 = CAST([Day] AS DATETIME) + CAST(DayFrom AS DATETIME)  
                                      FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @endtime AS DATETIME = (SELECT MyDateTime1 = CAST([Day] AS DATETIME) + CAST(DayTo AS DATETIME)  
                                      FROM INSERTED)
    DECLARE @waitingtime AS INT = (SELECT WaitingTime FROM INSERTED)

    WHILE (@starttime <= @endtime)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Booking] ([DoctorID], [Day], [Time], [Fees], [Valid],
                                     [PatientPhone], [BookingDayID],[PatientName], [PatientEmail],
                                     [NoShow], [PackageID], [IsFree],[IsEditable],
                                     [Shift], [CancelledByDoctor],[CancelledByUser],
                                     [UserId], [UpdatedBy])
        VALUES ((SELECT DoctorID FROM INSERTED),
                (SELECT [Day] FROM INSERTED),
                (SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(5), @starttime, 108)),
                (SELECT ExaminationFees FROM Doctor 
                 WHERE DoctorID = (SELECT DoctorID FROM INSERTED)), 1, NULL,
                (SELECT BookingDayID FROM INSERTED), NULL, NULL, 0,
                (SELECT [SubscribtionPackage] FROM Doctor 
                 WHERE DoctorID = (SELECT DoctorID FROM INSERTED)), 0, 0,
                (SELECT [Shift] FROM INSERTED), 0, 0,
                (SELECT UserId FROM INSERTED),
                (SELECT UpdatedBy FROM INSERTED))

        SET @starttime = DATEADD(minute, @waitingtime, @starttime)
    END
END
```

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what the problem is without schema and sample data. Have you tried running each of the subqueries in the insert individually to see if any return more than 1 value?

Comment: What Database ?

Comment: You should be able to ditch the insert..values in favour of insert..select

Comment: Also inserted may contain many rows - which is the cause of the error

Comment: @wobr yes and it returns 1 value

Comment: You are not taking into account the fact that the `inserted` table can have multiple rows in it. The way you've written the insert with subqueries cannot ever run well, because those subqueries should return at most one row. You're getting that error because the subqueries return more than one row.

Comment: @P.Salmon this is the solution >>Also inserted may contain many rows  << please put it in answer to mark it as the solution

Comment: As others have noted, triggers fire per _statement_, not _row_. If you don't want to handle that, just check the count of rows in `inserted` and `throw` if it is more than one. Bad idea, but doable. Triggers should also be fast to minimize performance impacts. Instead of looping you should rework the code to `join` a _numbers_ (aka _tally_) table so that only one `insert` is needed to handle multiple inserted rows and all of the "waiting" timesteps for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserted may contain many rows - which is the cause of the error. You should probably ditch the values insert method and replace with the select insert method possibly like this

```
SELECT I.DoctorID 
           ,i.[Day] 
            , convert(char(5), @starttime, 108)
           ,d.ExaminationFees
           ,1
           ,null
           ,i.BookingDayID 
           ,null
           ,null
           ,0
           ,d.[SubscribtionPackage]
           ,0
           ,0
           ,i.[Shift]
           ,0,0,
           i.UserId,
           i.UpdatedBy
From INSERTED i
join doctor d on d.DoctorID=i.doctorid
```

I have no way of telling how doctor relates to inserted so you may need to adjust to your needs.